# Uploading from Azure Pipeline fails but works from terminal

Tags: android, azure-devops, apk, firebase-app-distribution

I am working to get the azure pipeline yaml to upload the generated apk from the build.
The build agent is a Windows machine. I am working from a mac terminal.
When I upload from the mac terminal, there is no problem with uploading.

When I attempt to upload or distribute from the azure devops pipeline, it gives me this error.

> Error: Unsupported file format, should be .ipa, .apk or .aab

The step that fails in the yaml

```
- script: |
    firebase appdistribution:distribute '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\myapp.apk'  --app "$(FIREBASE_APP_ID)" --token "$(FIREBASE_TOKEN)"
```

I have tried double backslash, forward slash in the path, but it does not seem to solve it.  Any input is appreciated.

I expect the apk to be uploaded to firebase app distribution.
It works from the mac terminal.

Updates:
Using path expressions inside of the yaml script causes the firebase tool to not ignore the ending quote.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/src/appdistribution/distribution.ts.   So I changed that script or step to change the working directory and use just the name of the apk.

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Deploy APK to Firebase'
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk'
    script: |
      firebase appdistribution:distribute myapp.apk  --app "$(my-firebase-appid)" --token "$(FIREBASE_TOKEN)"
```

Comment: Hi @seank, Glad to know the issue was resolved. Would you mind sharing your findings to use `firebase` command from a different `workingDirectory` as an **answer** below? It may help other community members encountering similar issues. Thanks.